# Are power supplies with different frequencies an issue for charging my phone?

Tags: electronic-items, power, peru

This question can sound stupid, but better ask then see your device burnt :)

I'm going to Peru for a trip, and the power supplies there have the same voltage as where I live (220-230 volts) but slightly different frequency: **60 Hz** instead of **50 Hz**.

Is this an issue for my device? Or is it something I should not worry about at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of such chargers will work with a wide array of voltages and frequencies. It's not uncommon for chargers to be specified as **100-240 VAC 50-60 Hz**, which will work essentially anywhere in the world (where there is a public power grid) with simply a physical adapter for the plug.

@[MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/11288/2397) is right that in the case of a cell phone charger it *probably* doesn't matter, but if you want to be certain, the only *real* answer is to look at the charger itself and see what it says. If it says (for example) **100-240 VAC 50 Hz**, it might work but it also might not work. If it says **200-240 VAC 50-60 Hz**, you'll be fine. And so on. Note that VAC may alternatively be written V~.

Comment: +1, pretty much what I was going to post. Some [further evidence here](http://www.austech.info/electronics/48483-electrical-frequency-50-vh-60-hz-impact-battery-charging.html): "Most consumer items these days incorporating SMPS are rated between 90 and 260 Volts @ 50/60 Hz.", or from looking at [just about any electrical device](http://i.imgur.com/fPFQr.jpg) near me.

Answer (score 4):

from [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/can-i-use-a-50-hz-device-in-a-60-hz-power-frequency):

> The **60 Hz** represents the frequency at which the voltage in the wire oscillates. Heating elements don't care about this, and neither do most electronic components as they turn this alternating current (AC) into constant (DC) direct current anyway.
>
> If this is an all-singing, all-dancing, computer controlled extra-fancy espresso machine then I'd steer clear, though, as there's a remote chance you've one of the few devices where the cycles-per-second makes a difference. If it just uses power to heat an element you should be fine.
>
> Disclaimer: operating the device outside of the region it's designed for will certainly void the warranty, and coffee in excess isn't good for you anyway.

Read the other answers in the [original post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1134/can-i-use-a-50-hz-device-in-a-60-hz-power-frequency).